# Align filtered results in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

`Sheet 1`, `Sheet 2` & `Sheet 3` are in a single file.

`Sheet 1` (In order) [large list]

```
Name  Email
A     A@xyz //means A's email is A@xyz
B     B@xyz
C     C@xyz
D     D@xyz
E     E@xyz
...
...
```

`Sheet 2` (In order) [large list]

```
Name  Email
F     F@xyz
G     G@xyz //means G's email is G@xyz
H     H@xyz
...
...
```

`Sheet 3` (Out of order) [smaller list, *filtered* (from another source)]

```
Name  Email
B     A@xyz
A     D@xyz
D     B@xyz
F     H@xyz
G     F@xyz
...
...
```

I'm expecting `Sheet 3` to be like:

```
Name  Email
B     B@xyz
A     A@xyz
D     D@xyz
F     F@xyz
G     G@xyz
...
...
```

How do I map names to correct email-ids in `Sheet 3`?

**Note:** There's **no** such case that a name is present but corresponding email-id is not and vice-versa.

Comment: Welcome. _How do I align the names and email-ids in Sheet 3?_ It's not clear what you mean by "align" the names and email-ids. Would you please be more specific, and also provide an example of how a successful outcome would appear. I note that "A" (Sheet 1) email = "A@xyz" but the email on Sheet3 = "D@xyz"; presumably this is what you are driving at, but it is still unclear what outcome you want.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up, I've edited the post, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: So, do you have *two* worksheets with Names and Emails as a source instead of one?

Comment: All of them (sheet 1, 2 & 3) are in the same spreadsheet (one file). The filtered `sheet 3` is a bit lo..ong for me to describe (and that process messed up the order). But I don't mind having two other columns in `sheet 3` that maps names to correct emails... which can be logically derived from `sheet 1` & `sheet 2`... but I'm having trouble finding so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since basically you got 2 sources of data then, try in `Sheet3!B2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet1!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)),))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tired but I get `Function VLOOKUP parameter 3 value is 0. It should be greater than or equal to 1.` | `#VALUE` in certain cells, but I'm sure that all the names & email-ids in `Sheet 3` exists either in `Sheet 1` or in `Sheet 2`.

Comment: Also, it populates two columns of email-ids, but the positions are correct when compared with the name list in `Sheet 3`.

Comment: @JovialJoeJayarson, it will be halpfull if you can share a copy of your sheet in your original posting

Comment: I'm not permitted to, I'm sorry. let me see if I can create a demo...

Comment: thanks a lot! Got it, there was an error from my part in the formula.. :facepalm:

Comment: A great. Glad it is solved @JovialJoeJayarson. If you want, you can close the question by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Will do, thank you!